# Whitespace terminators & MakePlusRule in Irony

Tags: c#, parsing, grammar, irony

I'm trying to create a fairly simple parser using [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/), but am coming to the conclusion that Irony may not be suitable in this particular case.

These is an example of what I'm trying to parse:

```
server_name  example.com  *.example.com  www.example.*; 

server_name  www.example.com   ~^www\d+\.example\.com$;

server_name   ~^(?<subdomain>.+?)\.(?<domain>.+)$;
```

I'm using FreeTextLiterals with either a space or semi-colon as a terminator

```
var serverNamevalue = new FreeTextLiteral("serverNameValue", FreeTextOptions.None, " ", ";");
```

I'm then using the MakePlusRule to pick up one or more server_name values:

```
httpCoreServerName.Rule = "server_name" + httpCoreServerNameItems + semicolon;
httpCoreServerNameItems.Rule = MakePlusRule(httpCoreServerNameItems, serverNamevalue);
```

However - I think there's a problem with having whitespace as a terminator for the FreeTextLiteral in this case. When I run this, I get a parser error. If I substitute the whitespace for another specific character to act as terminator (and also add this a delimiter in the call to MakePlusRule) - it works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could deal with this in Irony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question over at the [Irony project on Codeplex](https://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/455287) where Roman Ivantsov - the developer of Irony - confirmed there was an issue with the parser when using semi-colons with FreeTextLiterals.

Roman has helpfully fixed / patched this issue. I've dowloaded the latest source and can confirm it's fixed the issue.